# how to recognize a bowling split in sql

Tags: sql, mysql

Someone brought up a SQL challenge and I couldn't come up with a good solution to it. They wanted to see the best way to detect a split in a game of bowling.

For some background, what I could find on defining a split from usbc:

```
2h. Split
A split is a setup of pins left standing after the first delivery, provided the head pin is down and at least one pin is down:
1. Between two or more standing pins; e.g., 7-9 or 3-10.
2. Immediately ahead of two or more standing pins; e.g., 5-6.
```

So presume we have a table as such...

```
gameid | throwNum | frame | pinsHit
1      | 1        | 1     | 1,2,3,6,7,9,10 -- 4,5,6 standing
1      | 1        | 2     | 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9 -- 3,10 standing
1      | 1        | 3     | 1,2,3,5,8,9 -- 4,6,7,10 standing
1      | 1        | 4     | 1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 -- 2,3 standing
1      | 1        | 5     | 1,2,3,4,5,8,10 -- 6,7,9 standing
```

For simplicity I only wrote out the first throw of each frame. All of these should constitute a split, but I can't think of the SQL to detect that without hard coding it.

I feel like I need to loop through the standing pins to look for the adjacent option first. Then I need to compare the other pin. I think this still requires hard coding, and I don't want to do this for every possible scenario

Comment: Using a relational database to store comma-separated values makes the challenge double: you need to come up with an algorithm for the problem itself and then you have figure out a way to apply it to stringified data using a declarative language.

Comment: What is the "head pin"? Do both of those conditions need to be met or only one?

Comment: The headpin is the first pin, ie, "1"

Comment: You can describe all possible combinations of the remaining pins for split as table Splits values (7,10), (7,9),(8,10), (5,7),(5,7,10),(3,7),(2,10),(2,7), (3,10),(2,7,10),(3,7,10),(4,7,10),(6,7,10),(4,6,7,10) ... or vice versa, as a combination of knocked-down pins (1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9) vs(3,10) as a Splits table. Then ``JOIN on pinsHit=Splits.PinsHit`` or ``JOIN on pinsStand=Splits.PinsStand``

Comment: I would normalize the design to 1NF at least. Then it becomes a lot easier.

Comment: Question: Should the combinations 2-4-5-7-9 and 3-5-6-8-10 (5-pin V patterns) both be considered splits? By rule 1 is should be, but I was experimenting with different logic that would say "no". The latter seems more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm below has three parts:

1. Using a recursive `cte`, the pin hits are normalized, standing pins are added, and the gaps between runs of standing and hit pins are found.
2. Then, in `frame_results`, the gap `id`s are grouped, and the size of the gaps and the type of gap (standing or hit pins) are recorded.
3. Finally, in the main query, there is a check to ensure the head pin is hit and either a hit pin exists directly after a run of standing pins of length `2` or more or there is a hit pin between two or more standing pins.

---

```
with recursive cte(gameid, thrownum, frame, pinsHit, ps, ct, rid, f) as (
   select r.*, case when cast(regexp_substr(r.pinsHit, '^\\d+') as float) = 1 then regexp_replace(r.pinsHit, '^\\d+,*', '') else r.pinsHit end, 1, 
     cast(regexp_substr(r.pinsHit, '^\\d+') as float) = 1, cast(regexp_substr(r.pinsHit, '^\\d+') as float) = 1
   from rounds r
   union all
   select c.gameid, c.thrownum, c.frame, c.pinsHit, 
      case when cast(regexp_substr(c.ps, '^\\d+') as float) = c.ct + 1 then regexp_replace(c.ps, '^\\d+,*', '') else c.ps end, c.ct + 1, 
      c.rid + (case when cast(regexp_substr(c.ps, '^\\d+') as float) = c.ct + 1 then c.f != 1 else c.f != 0 end), 
     coalesce(cast(regexp_substr(c.ps, '^\\d+') as float) = c.ct + 1, 0)
   from cte c where c.ct + 1 < 11
),
frame_results as (
   select c.gameid, c.thrownum, c.frame, c.rid, count(*) c1, max(c.f) m1, max(c.ct) m2 
   from cte c group by c.gameid, c.thrownum, c.frame, c.rid
)
select r.*, cast(regexp_substr(r.pinsHit, '^\\d+') as float) = 1 and 
   exists (select 1 from frame_results r1 where r1.gameid = r.gameid and 
     r1.thrownum = r.thrownum and r1.frame = r.frame and 
     ((r1.c1 > 1 and r1.m1 = 0 and r1.m2 + 1 < 11) or r1.rid >= 4)) is_split
from rounds r
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/volnzQVg) (Includes additional test cases)

Comment: @Alax1234 -(revised) I was comparing results [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/IeXkDwwK) using generated test data and (if my interpretation is correct) found a few false hits and misses. Pin standing combinations 9-10, 8-9-10, up through 2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10 are not flagged as splits. There are also several apparent false hits like 2-4, 2-5, and 5-9. (I originally thought these involved head-pin cases, but I had misinterpreted the data, thinking 1 was an up pin, not a down pin.)

Comment: I took a deeper dive into your code.. From what I can tell, you appear to be applying a gaps-and-islands analysis, treating the pins as a linear collection of 10 data points. It's an interesting approach, but without logic that identifies pins in front of or behind other pins (pin 5 is behind the 2-3 and in front of the 7-8), I am not sure the expected results are achievable. If you can add a second dimension to the logic, this approach might still hold promise.

Answer (score 0):

I want to propose a solution that can be simply applied to determine whether the standing pins combination is `Split`.

There 1024 possible combinations of pins in bowling field.
Some of these combinations are called `Split`. According to the meaning of the term, it is clear that the remaining figures should be divided into 2 or more groups.However, there are some additional conditions, such as that Pin 1 must be hited. In the terminology used by the players, there are combinations that formally do not fit the condition, but are also called Split. Some of the most common, as well as the most difficult combinations to continue the game, have their own names.

Therefore, I suggest creating a table of possible combinations and determining in it whether this combination is Split. Having such a table, the solution to the problem is quite simple.

```
select r.*,isSplit
  ,pinsStand,vHit,vStand,SplitName,Id
from rounds r
left join Splits s on r.pinsHit=s.pinsHit
order by gameid,thrownum,frame;
```

For example

| gameid | throwNum | frame | pinsHit | isSplit | pinsStand | vHit | vStand | SplitName | Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1,2,3,6,7,9,10 | 0 | 4,5,8 | 871 | 152 |  | 871 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9 | 1 | 3,10 | 507 | 516 | Baby Splits | 507 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 1,2,3,5,8,9 | 1 | 4,6,7,10 | 407 | 616 |  | 407 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 | 0 | 2,3 | 1017 | 6 |  | 1017 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 1,2,3,4,5,8,10 | 1 | 6,7,9 | 671 | 352 |  | 671 |
| 1 | 1 | 6 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 | 0 |  | 1023 | 0 |  | 1023 |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10 | 0 | 7 | 959 | 64 |  | 959 |
| 1 | 1 | 8 | 1,2,3,8,10 | 0 | 4,5,6,7,9 | 647 | 376 |  | 647 |
| 1 | 1 | 9 | 1,2,5,8 | 1 | 3,4,6,7,9,10 | 147 | 876 | Greek cathedral | 147 |

Such a table `Splits` can be created and filled like this:

1.Define  pins and pins neighbourhood. This is the field where we will place the elements of the `standPins` set

```
create table pins(pin int);
insert into pins values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
create table PinLink (pin1 int,pin2 int);
insert into PinLink values
 (1,2),(1,3)
,(2,1),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5)
,(3,1),(3,2),(3,5),(3,6)
,(4,2),(4,5),(4,7),(4,8)
,(5,2),(5,3),(5,4),(5,6),(5,8),(5,9)
,(6,3),(6,5),(6,9),(6,10)
,(7,4),(7,8)
,(8,4),(8,5),(8,7),(8,9)
,(9,5),(9,6),(9,8),(9,10)
,(10,6),(10,9)
;
```

2.And check the complete connectivity of the set on this undirected graph.
Perhaps this is the most interesting part of the task.

```
create table Splits(id int,vHit int,pinsHit varchar(30),vStand int
  ,pinsStand varchar(30),standCount int,isSplit int,SplitName varchar(30));

 SET SESSION cte_max_recursion_depth = 1024;

insert into Splits (id,vHit,vStand,pinsHit,pinsStand,standCount,isSplit,SplitName) 
with recursive  r as(
  select 0 
  union all
  select v+1
  from r where v< 1023
)
select id,vHit,vStand
  ,case when standCount<10 then left(pinsHit,char_length(pinshit)-0) 
   else pinsHit
   end pinsHit
  ,case when standCount>0 then left(pinsStand,char_length(pinsStand)-0) 
   else pinsStand
   end pinsStand
  ,standCount
  ,0 isSplit
  ,'' SplitName
from(
select
  v id,v vHit, ~v&1023 vStand 
  ,concat_ws(','
   ,case when (v&1)>0 then '1' end 
  ,case when (v&2)>0 then '2' end  
  ,case when v&4>0 then '3' end  
  ,case when v&8>0 then '4' end  
  ,case when v&16>0 then '5' end  
  ,case when v&32>0 then '6' end  
  ,case when v&64>0 then '7' end  
  ,case when v&128>0 then '8' end  
  ,case when v&256>0 then '9' end  
  ,case when (v&512)>0 then '10' end  
  ) pinsHit
  ,concat_ws(','
   ,case when v&1=0 then '1' end 
   ,case when v&2=0 then '2'end  
   ,case when v&4=0 then '3'end  
   ,case when v&8=0 then '4' end  
   ,case when v&16=0 then '5' end  
   ,case when v&32=0 then '6' end  
   ,case when v&64=0 then '7' end  
   ,case when v&128=0 then '8' end  
   ,case when v&256=0 then '9' end  
   ,case when v&512=0 then '10' end  
   )  pinsStand
  ,10 - bit_count(v) standCount
from r
) tmp
;
-- some examples 
select * from Splits  
where vHit in(871,507,407,1017,671,1023,959,647,147,576)  
order by id;
```

3. Check completly conectivity.

We take the first (any) element of the set and traverse the tree with a recursive query. If as a result we go through all the elements of the set, then the set is completely connected on this graph and the combination is not Split. Otherwise, they are called `disconnected` - Split.

```
with recursive rG as(
select 0 lvl 
   ,left(pinsStand,locate(',',concat(pinsStand,','))-1) head
   ,cast(left(pinsStand,locate(',',concat(pinsStand,','))-1) as char) St1
  ,id,pinsHit,pinsStand,vStand
--  ,cast(left(pinsStand,locate(',',concat(pinsStand,','))-1) as signed) p1
  ,cast(left(pinsStand,locate(',',concat(pinsStand,','))-1) as signed) p2
  ,concat(left(pinsStand,locate(',',concat(pinsStand,','))-1),',') sPath
from Splits  where standCount>1
 union all
select lvl+1 lvl , head
  ,cast(pl.pin2 as char) St1
  ,id,pinsHit,pinsStand,vStand
  -- ,pl.pin1
  ,pl.pin2
  ,cast(concat(sPath,cast(pl.pin2 as char),',') as char) sPath
from rG  inner join PinLink pl on  pl.pin1= St1
  and locate(concat(pl.pin2,','),concat(pinsStand,','))>0
  and locate(concat(pl.pin2,','),spath)=0
  where lvl<11
)

update Splits 
join (
  select id,pinsHit,pinsStand
    ,group_concat(p2 order by p2 separator ',') gap
    ,case   -- update 2 - check pin1 is stand 
         when locate('1,',concat(pinsStand,','))>0 then 0 
         when pinsStand<>group_concat(p2 order by p2 separator ',') then 1
     else 0
     end fSplit
  from (
    select distinct head,id,pinsHit
       ,pinsStand
       ,vStand,p2 
    from rG 
    )rG
   group by id,pinsHit,pinsStand
)y on y.id=Splits.id
  set isSplit=case when standCount>1 then fsplit else 0 end
;
update Splits
  set SplitName=
    case when pinsStand='7,10' then 'goal posts, bedposts, or snake eyes'
         when pinsStand in('7,9','8,10') then 'Cincinnati'
         when pinsStand in('5,7','5,10') then 'Woolworth/Kresge/Dime store'
         when pinsStand in('5,7,10') then 'Sour apple, Lily, Full Murray, or Three wise men'
         when pinsStand in('2,7','3,10') then 'Baby split or Murphy'
    else SplitName
  end
;
```

Table is ready. The table can be created 1 time and stored in the database.
Some examples

```
select * from Splits  
where vHit in(0,871,507,407,1017,671,1023,959,647,147,576)  
order by id;
```

| id | vHit | pinsHit | vStand | pinsStand | standCount | isSplit | SplitName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |  | 1023 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 | 10 | 0 |  |
| 147 | 147 | 1,2,5,8 | 876 | 3,4,6,7,9,10 | 6 | 1 |  |
| 407 | 407 | 1,2,3,5,8,9 | 616 | 4,6,7,10 | 4 | 1 |  |
| 507 | 507 | 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9 | 516 | 3,10 | 2 | 1 |  |
| 576 | 576 | 7,10 | 447 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9 | 8 | 0 |  |
| 647 | 647 | 1,2,3,8,10 | 376 | 4,5,6,7,9 | 5 | 0 |  |
| 671 | 671 | 1,2,3,4,5,8,10 | 352 | 6,7,9 | 3 | 1 |  |
| 871 | 871 | 1,2,3,6,7,9,10 | 152 | 4,5,8 | 3 | 0 |  |
| 959 | 959 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10 | 64 | 7 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 1017 | 1017 | 1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 | 6 | 2,3 | 2 | 0 |  |
| 1023 | 1023 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  |

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/udY5CB1Y) and [updated](https://dbfiddle.uk/vxxsoc8a)

Remark 1. I was considering `Split` = `disconnected`

Update2.  About vHit and vStand. I use numbers for convenient, concise designations of combinations.

We can denote any combination of 10 pins with number from 0 to 1023 or binary number with 10 bit.
The set of Pins {1,3,5,7} as number 0001010101 in binary notation, where 1 - standPin,0 - hitPin.
Another example

```
standPins      ({7,5,4,2})
   --bit number 987654321    
{2,4,5,7}     =0001011010 =hex 0x05A=0+2+0+8+16+0+64+0+0=90=vStand.  
And on the contrary, if hitPins 
{1,3,6,8,9,10)=1110100101 =hex 0x3A5=1+0+4+0+0+32+0+128+256+512=933=vHit.

All pins{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}=1111111111=0x3FF=1023
Empty{}=0000000000=0x000=0
``
hitPins=1023^standPins (XOR operation), hitPins+standPins=1023
Numbers from 0 to 1023 describe all possible combinations of 10 pins
```

Comment: I'm digesting this a bit still, but what is vHit and vStand? I haven't figured those two out yet. I do however like the idea using a "connected" table for the pins.

Comment: @JohnSly - Looks like bit mapped pins. 1 = pin 1, 2 = pin2, 4 = pin3, 8 = pin4, ... (powers of two).

Comment: @ValNik - I was comparing results [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/c2uzm757) using generated test data and (if my interpretation is correct) found a few misses. Side-by-side pin combinations like the 2-3, 4-5, or 7-8 are not being flagged as splits. Wider gaps 4-6, 7-9, 8-10, and 7-10 are. I also saw some false hits, but most seemed to be headpin cases. You may need to add the headpin standing = no split ever rule. Two other exceptions were the 2-8 and 3-9 double-wood cases which were tagged as splits.

Comment: I add check for pin1 is standing. As a rule  ``A split is a situation in ten pin bowling in which the first ball of a frame knocks down the headpin ("number 1 bowling pin") but leaves standing two or more non-adjacent groups of one or more pins.``  We check ``non-adjacent groups``. Combination 2-3,4-5, or 7-8 - ``adjacent``. 2-8 - not adjacent.

Comment: Rule 2 covers those. Missing 1 ahead of 2-3, missing 2 ahead of 4-5, and missing 5 ahead of 7-8. Although adjacent, ball placement must be precise to strike both pins, so these and similar are considered splits (side-by-side splits).

Comment: If you follow the definition, it is quite clear what Split is. However, in the game, this term refers to combinations of pins that are difficult to win with the next hit. These combinations may not fit the formal definition. Therefore, you need to manually specify this attribute in the table for each combination. You can also specify combinations called ``washouts``, which are also difficult to pass, but pin1 stand after the first hit.

Comment: You are using a different definition that the OP - possibly the lede on the Wikipedia page (or a mirror site). The definition that the OP included was extracted from the USBC site - presumably [this document](https://bowl.com/getmedia/00b3ea52-567e-43d6-b93a-e26d83d1b5bb/Rulebook-23-24.pdf). Item **2h** under *Basic Playing Rules* on page 11 matches the OP definition and cites the 5-6 among others as examples. My experience from league play is that side-by-sides were always marked as splits (both manually and with automatic scoring).  Doesn't affect scoring though. Agree to disagree?

Comment: Yes, I was guided by the description in Wikipedia page. You have experience playing in the league, so I don't insist on my understanding of the rules. I found the task interesting precisely as the definition of disconnected set on an undirected graph. However, life is richer than abstractions:)

Comment: Since the definition of a position as Split is determined more by practice than theory, the idea of having a table that reflects the rules that are practically applied seems to me the most appropriate. This table may reflect the specific requirements of the customer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that uses the pin set topology (10 rows of seed data) to build a short list of up/down pin combinations (24 rows) that constitutes a split. These can then be compared against any of the possible pin combinations (2^10 = 1024 possibilities) to determine if that combination constitutes a split.

**Strategy:** The logic takes a different approach from the posted definition. It considers the pins to be like dominos that only fall straight back and strike the two immediately behind and perhaps a third straight back (double-wood). If there exists a single domino near the front the set that can knock down all remaining dominos, we do not have a split. Two exceptions to this are the 2-4-5-7-9 and 3-5-6-8-10 (5-pin V pattern) combinations. By rule 1 these are considered splits, so we also have logic that tests for missing middle pins in the same row as others.  We also include a head-pin check that overrides all else.

Some of the reference cases might match pin combinations where the reference case does not itself constitute a split, but this will only occur for layouts where at least one other rule would apply, possibly to other pins.  For example, for a  4-5-7-8-9 pin set, the "7-9, missing 2" reference split would match, even though pins 7 and 9 are completely covered and part of a cluster. However, the "4-5 missing 2" reference case also matches, so this a still a split.

The logic is summarized as follows:

1. Define the set of 10 pins along with the associated bit mask position and a 3-axis coordinate value representing the pin's location - front-to-back, diagonals left-to-right, and diagonals right-to-left.
2. For each pin combination (excluding the head pin), use the coordinates to find the common leading/covering pin, and all intermediate pins to and from that common leading pin. If the two current pins are on the same row, also include any pins in between on the same row. The choses pins become the "up pins" while all the others (excluding the up-pins) become the "down pins". If the down-pin set is empty, this pin combination cannot be a split and may be skipped. The resulting 24 reference cases are stored in a table.
3. To test whether a particular pin combination is a split, check the reference table for any matches where all (both) of the up-pins are present and at least one of the down-pins is absent. If we have any matches, the combination being checked is a split. A check for the head pin (pin 1) standing is also made and if present, the result is always a no-split, overriding the match logic.
4. A lookup table of all 1024 pin combinations is also generated, and the "is split" indicator is set for each.
5. Once the above is defined, the test for any arbitrary pin combination is just a simple table lookup.

Pin combinations are stored as a bits in an integer and comparisons are performed using bitwise operations.

See **[this MySql fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zQ8yuDre)** or the equivalent **[this SQL-Server fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VadKSWWj)** for a demo.

The results include the sample cases, plus an exhaustive list of all 1024 pin combinations (from no pins to all 10 pins up). The results also contains extra columns showing the up/down pin lists and a visualization of the remaining pin combinations.  The last query is just a data generator that can be used to test other other answers. Game 111 contains all splits and game 222 contains all not-splits (at least per my interpretation of the rules).

The code it not minimal. It contains some repeated logic that could be made into functions. It also calculated several text results that are only present for information and debugging purposes.

Define pin number/name/mask/coordinates lookup table:

```
-- Define pins, bit mask value, and 3-axis coordinates
CREATE TABLE Pins (
    PinNumber INT,
    PinName   VARCHAR(100),
    BitMask   INT,  --  Pin 1 = 1, Pin 2 = 2, Pin 3 = 4,... , Pin 10 = 512
    RowNum    INT, -- Row number counting from front
    XCoord    INT, -- Row number counting from left
    YCoord    INT  -- Row number counting from right
);

INSERT INTO Pins
VALUES
    ( 1, '1',    1, 1, 1, 1),
    ( 2, '2',    2, 2, 1, 2),
    ( 3, '3',    4, 2, 2, 1),
    ( 4, '4',    8, 3, 1, 3),
    ( 5, '5',   16, 3, 2, 2),
    ( 6, '6',   32, 3, 3, 1),
    ( 7, '7',   64, 4, 1, 4),
    ( 8, '8',  128, 4, 2, 3),
    ( 9, '9',  256, 4, 3, 2),
    (10, '10', 512, 4, 4, 1);
```

Generate reference split data.

```
-- Table to hold base set of split cases
CREATE TABLE SplitConditions (
    PinsUp VARCHAR(100),   -- All (both) of these pins are up
    PinsDown VARCHAR(100), -- Any of these pins are down
    PinsUpBitMask INT,
    PinsDownBitMask INT
);

INSERT SplitConditions
SELECT PU.PinsUp,  PD.PinsDown, PU.PinsUpBitMask,PD.PinsDownBitMask
FROM Pins P1
JOIN Pins P2
    ON P2.PinNumber > P1.PinNumber,
LATERAL (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(P1.PinName, ',', P2.PinName) AS PinsUp,
        P1.BitMask + P2.BitMask AS PinsUpBitMask
) PU,
LATERAL (
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(P3.PinName ORDER BY P3.PinNumber, ',') AS PinsDown,
        SUM(P3.BitMask) AS PinsDownBitMask
    FROM Pins P3
    WHERE P3.PinNumber NOT IN (P1.PinNumber, P2.PinNumber)
    AND (
        ( -- Pins along X axis to the common leading pin
            P3.XCoord = LEAST(P1.XCoord, P2.XCoord)
            AND P3.YCoord >= LEAST(P1.YCoord, P2.YCoord) 
            AND P3.YCoord < GREATEST(P1.YCoord, P2.YCoord)
        )
        OR ( -- Pins along Y axis to the common leading pin
            P3.YCoord = LEAST(P1.YCoord, P2.YCoord)
            AND P3.XCoord >= LEAST(P1.XCoord, P2.XCoord) 
            AND P3.XCoord < GREATEST(P1.XCoord, P2.XCoord)
        )
        OR ( -- Pins between on the same row
            P1.RowNum = P2.RowNum
            AND P3.PinNumber BETWEEN P1.PinNumber + 1 AND P2.PinNumber - 1
       )
    )
) PD
WHERE P1.PinNumber >= 2
AND PD.PinsDownBitMask > 0
ORDER BY P1.PinNumber, P2.PinNumber;
```

Visually, the cases generated above would be similar to the following, where "U" represents the two "up-pins" being considered, and where "d" represents the "down-pins", the absence of any would either directly or *indirectly* constitute a split.

```
U . . .    . . U U    U . . .    . U d U
 d . .      . . d      d . U      . d d
  U .        . .        d d        . d
   .          .          d          .
```

Now we can calculate the results for an arbitrary pin collection by converting the hit-pin list to a pair of up-pin and down-pin bit masks and scanning the reference data for any rows where *all* up-pins match and *any* down-pin matches.

```
SELECT TD.*, S.IsSplit
FROM TestData TD,
LATERAL (
    -- Map pinsHit to bitsets
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(P.BitMask), 0) AS PinsDownBitMask
    FROM Pins P
    WHERE CONCAT(',', TD.pinsHit, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', P.PinName, ',%')
) PD,
LATERAL (
    -- PinsUpBitMask is inverse of PinsDownBitMask
    SELECT 1023 - PD.PinsDownBitMask AS PinsUpBitMask
) PU,
LATERAL (
    -- Check for any maytches in the split reference table
    SELECT (
            PU.PinsUpBitMask & 1 = 0  -- Head pin is down
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM SplitConditions SC
                WHERE PU.PinsUpBitMask & SC.PinsUpBitMask = SC.PinsUpBitMask -- All
                AND PD.PinsDownBitMask & SC.PinsDownBitMask > 0 -- Any
            )
        ) AS IsSplit
) S;
```

Sample results:

| gameid | throwNum | frame | pinsHit | IsSplit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1,2,3,6,7,9,10 | True |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9 | True |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 1,2,3,5,8,9 | True |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 | True |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 1,2,3,4,5,8,10 | True |

Generate a reference table of all possible pin combinations and calculate the IsSplit value for each. (Note that some of the calculated data below is solely for debug presentation or visualization purposes.)

```
-- Table to hold every possible pin combination, both as lists and as bit maps
CREATE TABLE PinSet (
    PinsUp VARCHAR(100),
    PinsDown VARCHAR(100),
    PinsUpBitMask INT,
    PinsDownBitMask INT,
    Visual VARCHAR(100),
    IsSplit BIT
);

-- Generate data for all combinations
INSERT INTO PinSet
WITH DIgits AS (
    SELECT 0 AS val
    UNION ALL SELECT 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 5
    UNION ALL SELECT 6
    UNION ALL SELECT 7
    UNION ALL SELECT 8
    UNION ALL SELECT 9
),
CTE_Series_0_to_1023 AS (
  SELECT 1000 * D1.val + 100 * D2.val + 10 * D3.val + D4.val value
  FROM DIgits D1, DIgits D2, DIgits D3, DIgits D4
  ORDER BY D1.val, D2.val, D3.val, D4.val
  LIMIT 1024
)
SELECT
    COALESCE(PU.PinsUp, ''),  COALESCE(PD.PinsDown, '' ),
    M.PinsUpBitMask, M.PinsDownBitMask,
    V.Visual, SPL.IsSplit
FROM CTE_Series_0_to_1023 S,
LATERAL (
    SELECT
        S.value AS PinsUpBitMask,
        1023 - S.value AS PinsDownBitMask
) M,
LATERAL (
    -- Check for any maytches in the split reference table
    SELECT (
            M.PinsUpBitMask & 1 = 0  -- Head pin is down
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM SplitConditions SC
                WHERE M.PinsUpBitMask & SC.PinsUpBitMask = SC.PinsUpBitMask -- All
                AND M.PinsDownBitMask & SC.PinsDownBitMask > 0 -- Any
            )
        ) AS IsSplit
) SPL,
LATERAL (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(P.PinName ORDER BY P.PinNumber, '-') AS PinsUp
    FROM Pins P
    WHERE S.value & P.BitMask > 0
) PU,
LATERAL (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(P.PinName ORDER BY P.PinNumber, '-') AS PinsDown
    FROM Pins P
    WHERE (1023 - S.value) & P.BitMask > 0
) PD,
LATERAL (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(PV.PinVisual ORDER BY P.PinNumber, ' ') AS Visual1
    FROM Pins P,
    LATERAL (
        SELECT CASE WHEN S.value & P.BitMask > 0
            THEN P.PinName ELSE '.' END AS PinVisual
    ) PV
) V1,
LATERAL (
    SELECT CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(V1.Visual1, 13, 99), '\n'
        ' ', SUBSTRING(V1.Visual1, 7, 5), '\n'
        '  ', SUBSTRING(V1.Visual1, 3, 3), '\n'
        '   ', SUBSTRING(V1.Visual1, 1, 1), '\n'
        ) AS Visual
) V;
```

The split check is now just a lookup:

```
SELECT TD.*, PS.IsSplit
FROM TestData TD
LEFT JOIN PinSet PS
    ON PS.PinsDown = TD.pinsHit
```

One interesting statistic is that if you exclude the headpin-standing cases, of the remaining 512 pin combinations only 10% (51) are not considered splits. It is worth noting however that the great majority of split combinations (like a 4-5-6-7-8-9-10) would be nearly impossible to achieve is a real game.